# Custom Post Type Archive URL is wrong

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I'm using CPT UI and have several custom post types. Separately, I have my permalinks settings set to append /blog/ before all blog post single pages. I have the "with front" setting set to false on all my custom post types so that only my blog posts have /blog/ appended before each single post. All works as it should except one thing:

When I navigate to the archive of a custom post type (in this case "news") and click on a month, the url structure changes to mysite.com/blog/2017/02/?post_type=news How can I change the URL to not append "/blog/" before the archive page of a custom post type under this circumstance?

Thanks in advance for any help on this one.

Comment: You can check out [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-date-archives/) if you want a quick solution. Custom post types don't have the necessary rewrite rules to support date archives.